# Rails Custom Header for Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, http-headers

Is it possible to modify the HEADER in Rails 3 when someone requests an image? For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/myimg.png
```

I want to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" to the headers so I can download image files remotely via JavaScript.

**UPDATE 1**

I have the answer for images under the assets folder to change the headers, but now I also need to do the same thing for public images. I tried the same method below, but no luck.

Example url would be

```
http://localhost:3000/images/stuff.png
```

I tried the Rack MiddleWare, but it doesn't run the call method when going to a public image. I also tried LocationMatch (on a production environment), same no luck.

What do I try for the public images end to change Headers?

**UPDATE 2**

So, I did manage to get it working via LocationMatch, but the images can not cache. Is there a way to disable image caching via apache?

Comment: Where will you be hosting your app? How you can achieve this depends on your production environment, namely your server for static files.

Comment: Production will be done via Apache and development is WEBRICK.

Comment: In development mode it is quite hard to get any of the headers served (with reasonable code changes) as the files are served through ActionDispatch::Static (instead of Apache) there. I don't know how difficult it is to change the configuration in a way Ryan describes is in Apache, but you'd need to either replicate your production setup to get your headers (when Apache serves the files) or just test it in your production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assets will be "compiled" and served directly by the web server (Nginx/Apache) so Rails will not serve it in production. You will need to modify the configuration of your web server to add headers.

Something like this in Apache.

```
<LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  ...
</LocationMatch>
```

And this in Nginx.

```
location ~ ^/assets/ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
  ...
}
```

See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) for further details on precompiling assets.

**Update:** If you need to apply headers in the development environment you can do so with some custom rack middleware. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/4157256) for an example.

Comment: Awesome that would cover Production side. Thanks! How do I modify WEBRICK in development mode so I can test caching images in Phonegap via Javascript. Right now it keeps telling me about not allowed by origin .... until I fix the development side.

Comment: Or do I have to stop using WEBRICK and start using some other development system that would allow changing headers?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know of a way to configure the headers that Sprockets uses when it serves the asset pipeline. There may be a way but alternatively you can use a custom rack middleware in config/environments/development.rb. It can modify the headers that are being sent back for asset requests.

Comment: BTW, for the curious, the Sprockets::Server module is what handles the asset response. I don't see a way to configure the headers there: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/server.rb#L196

Comment: Is it possible to change the headers of images in the public/images folder?